# Module "Word" not found on custom class

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-class

I have a script1.py that is trying to call a custom class named Word.py that is in the same folder as the custom class. The directory is like this:

```
main/
├─ folder1/
│  ├─ __init__.py
│  ├─ script1.py
│  ├─ Word.py
├─ folder2/
│  ├─ __init__.py
│  ├─ script2.py
├─ __init__.py
├─ main.py
├─ __init__.py
```

On script1.py, I try to do the following:

```
import wave
import json

from vosk import Model, KaldiRecognizer, SetLogLevel
**from .Word import Word as custom_Word** 

model_path = "models/vosk-model-en-us-0.21"
audio_filename = "audio/speech_recognition_systems.wav"

model = Model(model_path)
wf = wave.open(audio_filename, "rb")
rec = KaldiRecognizer(model, wf.getframerate())
rec.SetWords(True)

# get the list of JSON dictionaries
results = []
# recognize speech using vosk model
while True:
    data = wf.readframes(4000)
    if len(data) == 0:
        break
    if rec.AcceptWaveform(data):
        part_result = json.loads(rec.Result())
        results.append(part_result)
part_result = json.loads(rec.FinalResult())
results.append(part_result)

# convert list of JSON dictionaries to list of 'Word' objects
list_of_Words = []
for sentence in results:
    if len(sentence) == 1:
        # sometimes there are bugs in recognition 
        # and it returns an empty dictionary
        # {'text': ''}
        continue
    for obj in sentence['result']:
       

       **# Here You need to call custom_Word only**

 
        w = **custom_Word(obj)**  # create custom Word object
        list_of_Words.append(w)  # and add it to list

wf.close()  # close audiofile

# output to the screen
for word in list_of_words:
    print(word.to_string())
```

I get the error no module named "Word" found.

The issue is that I've tried in another folder before with the script calling the class side by side and it worked. But now it doesn't.

I followed this tutorial that uses the class Word.py this way if you need further info: https://towardsdatascience.com/speech-recognition-with-timestamps-934ede4234b2

If anyone can point me in the right direction it would be great, thanks in advance.

The custom class is the following:

```
class Word:
    # A class representing a word from the JSON format for vosk speech recognition API 

    def __init__(self, dict):
        '''
        Parameters:
          dict (dict) dictionary from JSON, containing:
            conf (float): degree of confidence, from 0 to 1
            end (float): end time of the pronouncing the word, in seconds
            start (float): start time of the pronouncing the word, in seconds
            word (str): recognized word
        '''

        self.conf = dict["conf"]
        self.end = dict["end"]
        self.start = dict["start"]
        self.word = dict["word"]

    def to_string(self):
        ''' Returns a string describing this instance '''
        # return "{:20} from {:.2f} sec to {:.2f} sec, confidence is {:.2f}%".format(
        
        return "{:.2f} - {:.2f}\n{:20}".format(
            # self.word, self.start, self.end, self.conf*100)
            self.start, self.end, self.word)
```

EDIT: After @LietKynes posted an answer, I realized you also need, when instantiating the custom class, call the name that you defined the import as , in my case, custom_Word. I added what I changed to the question in bold.

Comment: It'd help to provide the [full error message with traceback](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146/4518341)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For python modules (`.py` files) that are being in a package (in a directory that has `__init__.py` file), the modules should use [relative import](https://peps.python.org/pep-0328/) to import from other modules in the same package:

```
from .Word import Word as custom_Word
```

Comment: When I try this, I get the error: 

    w =  custom_Word.Word(obj) 
AttributeError: type object 'Word' has no attribute 'Word'

Comment: I realized the issue was when instantiating the class in my main.py , where I needed to just use custom_word(obj). Thanks for your help.

Comment: Two things: 1. use lowercase filenames 2. Why do you need to alias the Word class as custom_Word? 3. Combining the above two, the import would be `from .word import Word`.

Comment: thank you for the tip, I'll try to do that from now on.